# Add tree component to OverFlowMenu

Tags: components, codenameone

I am using codename one to create an application, and i am in front of a situation that is making me use the "`tree component`" in the  `pop-up` of the `OverFlowMenu`

how can i do that?

Comment: I am using toolbar to add commands to the overflowmenu, but i am having issues in having component added to the overflowmenu, not the sidemenu

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. The overflow menu uses a renderer approach and isn't very customizable.

Instead add a command to the right side of the toolbar and show a popup dialog pointing at that button e.g.:

```
popupCommand = toolbar.addMaterialCommandToRightBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_MORE_VERT, e -> showPopup());


private void showPopup() {
    Button b = toolbar.findCommandComponent(popupCommand);
    Dialog popup = new Dialog(new BorderLayout());
    popup.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new Tree());
    popup.showPopup(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks shai, this looks to be the best way to do it, thanks, let me try to see how it will look like in the code, but i am intrested in the Tree component, but i want sub menu instead, for example  if i have a command named "Menu" in the overflow, once we click on it, we can have shown "Menu1" , "Menu2" as sub menus of "Menu", so not the Tree component itself,

Comment: You can use `Accordion` for this too.